# how to find difference between rows of same column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image]

question-> Write a query to display all those account number, deposit, withdrawal where withdrawal is more then deposit amount.

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: select acnumber,transaction_type,sum(transaction_amount) as amount
from trandetails
group by acnumber,transaction_type order by acnumber asc

not able to get the diff bet withdrawal and deposit for particular acnumber

Comment: @user5501922  Put that query as part of your question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this(you can also do it by SELF JOIN):

```
;WITH D AS
(
SELECT ACNUMBER, SUM(TRANSACTION) AS Deposit
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'Deposit'
GROUP BY ACNUMBER
)
, W as
(
SELECT ACNUMBER, SUM(TRANSACTION) AS Withdrawal
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'Withdrawal'
GROUP BY ACNUMBER

)
SELECT D.ACNUMBER, d.Deposit, w.Withdrawal

FROM D 
INNER JOIN W
ON D.ACNUMBER = W.ACNUMBER
WHERE d.Deposit < w.Withdrawal
```

Comment: This will not return any accounts where there is only one type of transaction.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'trandetails.acnumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

got this error while ruuniny your query @Mangal Pardeshi

Comment: Sorry you need to GROUP BY ACNUMBER in both the CTEs

Answer (score 0):

You should not group by transaction type. Try this

```
select acnumber,sum(transaction_amount * case when transaction_type = 'deposit' then 1 else -1 end) as amount 
from trandetails 
group by acnumber
order by acnumber asc
```

You may be interested only in rows where the amount is negative as these are the accounts where withdrawl > deposit. In that case add a filter:

```
select acnumber,sum(transaction_amount * case when transaction_type = 'deposit' then 1 else -1 end) as amount 
from trandetails 
group by acnumber
having sum(transaction_amount * case when transaction_type = 'deposit' then 1 else -1 end) < 0
order by acnumber asc
```